# How can I connect to the DB without without using @ symbol to connect to DB. call sqlplus UNAME@DBNAME/Password@\\Filelocation

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

How can I connect to the DB without  without using @ symbol to connect to DB.

```
sqlplus UNAME@DBNAME/Password@\\Filelocation
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the @ symbol? And which one - the `@DBNAME` (which is the TNS alias for the DB you're connecting to), or the `@\\Filelocation` which is a script to run?

Comment: @AlexPoole, I am not overly familiar with `sqlplus`, but I am wondering if there is an environmental that can be set for the script file name like you can for the connection string using `set local=mydb`?

Comment: @Squashman - no, not that I'm aware of. It would be an odd thing to support; `LOCAL` makes sense as you'd use the same value all the time (more or less), but you would use different file names for various tasks. I'm still not sure why you would want to do this. What are you trying to achieve by not using `@file`? You can use redirection or a heredoc instead (or Windows equivalents, I think in Unix-ish), but without knowing why it's hard to say what to use instead?

Comment: from the windows batch script I would like to connect to DB and the File location using Call sqlplus.When I mentioned  @ SQL Plus is thinking that DBNAME as file location. I hope SET LOCAL=DBNAME and then the call function will work. Let's see. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @Squashman - that might just be because you don't have a space before the second `@` ? Although that's malformed to SQL\*Plus shows the usage message, it doesn't treat it as a (second) TNS alias. It does if the the password comes before the first `@` though.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you set the `LOCAL` environment variable to the name of the DB you want to connect to, e.g.

```
set LOCAL=DBNAME
sqlplus UNAME @Filelocation
```

Will connect to DBNAME and then run the script `Filelocation`

[See here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/qstart.htm#i1055567).

Comment: I can able to connect Using SQL PLUS UID@DBNAME/PASSWD but In the command prompt while I am trying to connect "UID@DBNAME/Paswd @FileLOC" or "UID/Paswd@DBNAME @FileLOC" I am unable to connect and throwing TNS protocol Adapter error. TNS12560

Answer (score 0):

You showed:

```
sqlplus UNAME@DBNAME/Password@\\Filelocation
```

which just shows the SQL*Plus usage screen (in 11gR2 anyway). With the password before the TNS alias:

```
sqlplus UNAME/Password@DBNAME@\\Filelocation
```

it thinks the `@\\Filelocation` is the TNS alias and can't resolve that, so you get "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified". That seems to be what you're referring to in comments.

With or without a TNS alias, you need a space between the credentials and the `@file` part:

```
sqlplus UNAME/Password@DBNAME @\\Filelocation
```

or if you prefer that way around:

```
sqlplus UNAME@DBNAME/Password @\\Filelocation
```

or

```
set LOCAL=DBNAME
sqlplus UNAME/Password @\\Filelocation
```

In each case there has to be a space.

Comment: I can able to connect Using SQL PLUS UID@DBNAME/PASSWD but In the command prompt while I am trying to connect "UID@DBNAME/Paswd @FileLOC" or "UID/Paswd@DBNAME @FileLOC" I am unable to connect and throwing TNS protocol Adapter error. TNS12560